# How to find an integer set, s.t. the sums of at most 3 elements are all distinct?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sumsets, sidon-sets

How to find a set $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that any sum of at most three Elements $a_i \in A$ is different if at least one element in the sum is different.

**Example with $|A|=3$:** Out of the set $A := \{1,7,11\}$ follow 19 sums 1,2,3,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,18,19,21,22,23,25,29,33 which are all distinct!

Is there an algorithm to construct such sets for a given number of elements $n=|A|$ with the smallest maximum possible?

Comment: This is what I figured out so far:
Such sets are known as $B_k[1]$ sets. k is the number of elements in the sum. Therefore im interested in $B_3[1]$ sets. Sets with distinct sums of only two elements $B_2[1]$ are also known as Sidon sets.

Comment: The first place to turn for this kind of question is Richard Guy's book, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory. Unfortunately, I don't have it handy right now. Also, it won't be as up-to-date as Tony Huynh's answer, but it will give some context and history and references.

Answer (score 8):

There is an algorithm: look at all $n$-element subsets of $S:=\{1,2,3,\dots,4^{n-1}\}$. There is at least one $B_3[1]$ subset among them, namely $\{1,4,4^2,\dots,4^{n-1}\}$. So list all $n$-element $B_3[1]$ subsets of $S$, and pick the one with the smallest maximum.

Answer (score 7):

Note that there is a bit of a discrepancy between $B_3[1]$ sets and your notion.  For $B_3[1]$ sets, one considers sums with *exactly* 3 elements, instead of at most 3 elements.  However, I do not think this will make a big difference.  Basically the main point is that we can do much better than GH from MO's answer by taking a random subset of integers and using the probabilistic method.  Indeed, this was carried out by Erdős–Rényi for Sidon sets and claimed (but not proven) for $B_3[1]$ sets.  The first correct proof for $B_3[1]$ sets is attributed to Vu in this [thesis](http://www.icmat.es/Thesis/CVinuesa.pdf) of Carlos Vinuesa del Río.  That thesis also has the current state of the art for your problem.  See Theorem 2.1.2.  Specializing that result we have the following theorem.

**Theorem.** For any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an infinite $B_3[1]$ sequence $A$ such that $A(x) \gg x^{\frac{1}{5} - \epsilon}$.

Here $A(x)$ is the number of elements of $A$ that are at most $x$.

Comment: Note that the OP only asked if there is an algorithm to find a suitable set with given cardinality and smallest maximum. The possible answers to this question are "yes", "no", "undecidable". With all that, I appreciate your response which contains far more mathematics.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree that you completely answered the question as asked.  I +1ed it.

Comment: Isn't it enough to add $0$ to the set to get a $B_3[1]$ set? (Bearing in mind I have not looked up what $B_3[1]$ means...)

Answer (score 3):

The probabilistic method shows the existence of an infinite $B_h[1]$ sequence of positive integers $A$ with $A(x)>x^{1/(2h-1)+o(1)}$. The proof is easy for $h=2$ but involved for $h\ge 3$. In particular it gives the exponent $1/5$ for $h=3$.

Ruzsa improved the exponent $1/3$ to $\sqrt 2-1$ for $h=2$ and
very recently Cilleruelo, using a new method, improved the exponent $1/(2h-1)$  to $\sqrt{(h-1)^2+1}-(h-1)$ for any $h\ge 3$. 
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S000187081400022X

Furthermore, for $h=2$ this method provides an explicit $B_2[1]$ sequence $A$ with $A(x)>x^{\sqrt 2-1+o(1)}$.